# Core Data operations on multiple thread causing insertion but no fetching

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift5

I am using CoreData to insert data and fetch Data, as I have a lot of data, so I am using core data on multiple threads in order to be thread-safe.

The problem is that I am able to insert Data in CoreData, but while fetching from CoreData, the results are zero, **this is happening when I kill my app and fetch the data from Database**. This has something to do with `NSMangedObjectContext` but I am not able to figure it out.

Here is my code snippet :

```
class CoreDataManager {

    static let sharedManager = CoreDataManager()
    private init() {}

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "My_Contacts")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    func saveContext() {
        let context = CoreDataManager.sharedManager.persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

    func insertContact(id:Int, firstName : String,lastName : String,emaild : String,isFavorite : Bool,phoneNum : String,profilePic : String,sync : Bool) -> Contact? {
        let managedContext = CoreDataManager.sharedManager.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let privateManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
            //NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType
            let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
            moc.parent = managedContext
            return moc
        }()


        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Contact",
                                                in: privateManagedObjectContext)!
        let contact = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                     insertInto: privateManagedObjectContext)
        contact.setValue(firstName, forKey: "first_name")
        contact.setValue(lastName, forKey: "last_name")
        contact.setValue(emaild, forKey: "email")
        contact.setValue(isFavorite, forKey: "favorite")
        contact.setValue(phoneNum, forKey: "phone_number")
        contact.setValue(profilePic, forKey: "profile_pic")
        contact.setValue(sync, forKey: "syncStatus")
        contact.setValue(id, forKey: "contactId")

        do {
            try privateManagedObjectContext.save()
            return contact as? Contact
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            return nil
        }
    }


    func fetchAllContacts() -> [Contact]?{

        let managedContext = CoreDataManager.sharedManager.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Contact")

        do {
            let people = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            return people as? [Contact]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Confirm your save operation is successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so I am using core data on multiple threads in order to be thread-safe

What do you mean by this? Using multiple threads doesn't make anything thread-safe. Thread safety relates to your ability to run your code on multiple threads without problems, and it generally requires that you take a number of precautions to prevent threads from interfering with each other.

> The problem is that I am able to insert Data in CoreData, but while fetching from CoreData, the results are zero, this is happening when I kill my app and fetch the data from Database. This has something to do with NSMangedObjectContext but I am not able to figure it out.

You need to understand what a managed object context is. Think of it like a temporary workspace: you can execute a fetch request to bring objects from a persistent store into a managed object context, and you can add new objects to the context, and you can manipulate the objects in a context. The changes you make in a context don't mean anything outside the context until you save the context back to the persistent store.

A few reasons you might not be seeing the objects you're adding are:

- You're adding the objects and trying to read them back in different contexts.
- You never save the context after you add objects.
- You save the context in which you added the object, but the parent context (managed object contexts are hierarchical) is never saved.
- You try to save the context after you add objects, but saving fails.
- You're using the same context in multiple threads without taking care to serialize the operations on the context (which is to say, your code *isn't* thread-safe).

What you really should do to figure this out is to get yourself back to a state where you can store and retrieve objects reliably. Try using just one thread and make sure that your operations work. If they don't, fix that first. Next, get a solid understanding of how managed object contexts work and how to use them. Finally, read up on [concurrency and Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html).

Comment: Thankyou for the solid understanding,
I was not saving the parent context, hence the data was not persisted stored in persistant stores

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using multiple MOC(Managed Object Context), you need to **save both the contexts**

You have set `privateManagedObjectContext`'s parent to `managedContext`, but you are not saving `managedContext`

After calling `privateManagedObjectContext.save()`, you need to call `managedContext.save()` as well

Comment: yaa that was the problem which was occurring. Thank you :)

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal Thank You! If you think the answer helped you, please mark it as the accepted solution. Thanks

Comment: But this is blocking my main thread till the time my insertion operation completes

Comment: That's because your `managedContext` is your `viewContext` which belongs to your main thread

Comment: Yaa that i got it, but then how to save the parentContext without blocking the UI